# Firebase auth email&password trouble

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a Sign Up/Login page.

The first time I sign up a user, x@x.com, everything is okay.

Then I try logout and login, everything goes right.

But, once I refresh the page, I can't login anymore.
I thought I had erased all my users so tried to create the same user again (x@x.com), but got >"auth/email-already-in-use". But, after this attempt, I could sign in with x@x.com.

```
function signIn() {
    var email = document.getElementById("emailin").value
    console.log(email)
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function () {
        console.log("adentro")
        email.value = ""
        pass.value = ""
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode + errorMessage)

    });
}

function signUp() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value
    console.log(email)
    var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value
    if (email === email2 && pass != "") {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorCode + errorMessage)

        });

    }

}
function signOut() {
    console.log("signOut")
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
        // Sign-out successful.
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // An error happened.
    });

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you login and refresh the page, your user will be still logged in. You should make sure you wait for the auth system to initialise using `onAuthStateChanged` which will tell you what your initial state is (logged in / logged out). There's some good examples in this issue thread ~ https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462

Comment: Thanks Phil! I had a misspelling in a reference. Sorry to have bothered

Comment: All good, glad you got it sorted